# Why Does Excel Workbook with VBA and Macros Generate Error Message(s) When Saving?

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

We are using Microsoft 365 which is indicating Excel version 2401 (Build 17231.20236 Click-to-Run).  The workbook template we have been using has been in service for over three months, working without issue until yesterday. The user opened the template, enabled macros, populated the necessary fields then activated the rename button.  The rename button renames the workbook based on the fields populated and saves the file to a specific location.

The error message presented to user:

[Rename Button Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l0kg.png)

Next, the user attempted to Save As and was presented with this error message:

[Save As Error Msg Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogIcR.png)

Now the template file continues to give these errors and is unusable.  I have placed a backup template file in place which is working properly.  I have also compared the working file to the file with errors and cannot find any differences.

We have been presented with the second error message on three occasions over the past 45 days with other files.  All use similar macros and VBA that we have been using for several years without issue.

What has changed and what needs to be done to prevent or fix this issue?

Comment: Please create a [reprex], specifically providing all relevant code as text.

Comment: First step is find and remove every "on error resume next" and then try to create a minimal reproducible example. Look to see what "improvements" MS has made to Office365 recently - they tend to happen on Tuesdays. The code for whatever the rename button does looks like it is implicated in the problem but beyond that it is hard to say anything more. An aggressive AV scan might be a good idea if the old template file still works when restored but looks the same. File CRC's are worth checking - some viruses are good at faking the information that OS's expect to see.

Comment: It's possible the template is corrupted: this does occasionally happen and why it's always good practice to have [working] backups for important files.